# Parking fee using C

Tags: c

Beginner here. I just wanted to know how and where I went wrong with this code. I’m having problem with using the modulo for the time. The following is the problem and the code I created.

A company wants to create a system that automatically computes for the total fee of the parking services in their new mall.
The user first needs to input their vehicle type, time-in and time-out. Then, it will compute for the total fee of the parking service based on the time the vehicle spent parked. Use the table below as basis:
Vehicle Type First 3 hours After 3 hours
M-otorcycle FREE PHP 10.00/hr
C-ar PHP 30.00 PHP 10.00/hr
T-ruck PHP 50.00 PHP 25.00/hr

Assumptions:
User will not input a value wherein Timeout < Timein.
Max Inputs will for time will be from 0000 to 2359, and it will always follow that form (user will not input values like 13, 17, 110).
Input Format

Vehicle Type, Time-in, and Time-out
Input Sample

M
1230
1430
Output Format

Payment, hours and minutes in this format.
Output Sample

Payment:·0.00
Hours:·2
Minutes:·0

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

double payment;
int time, entry,exit;
int hours, minutes;
char type;

scanf("%c %d %d", &type, &entry, &exit);

hours = (exit-entry)/100;
minutes = (exit-entry) %60;

if (type == 'M' && time > 3)
payment = hours*10;
else
payment = hours*0;

if (type=='C' && time >= 3)
payment = ((hours-3)*10)+30;
else
payment = 30;

if (type == 'T' && hours >= 3)
payment = ((hours-3)*25)+50;
else
payment = 50;

printf("Payment: %.2f \nHours: %d \nMinutes: %d ", payment, hours, minutes);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is kinda all over the place.  Your `if` statements compare with `time` but you never set `time`.
You don't want to use % 60 in this format you're using.  You simply want to get the lower portion, so just as you did / 100 for hours, you  need to do % 100 to get the minutes.
That's all I see off the cuff for now.
You never use minutes

Comment: My bad. I forgot to change time to hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can u send the table clearly.
And also,

```
minutes = abs((exit/100) - (entry/100));
```

No use of modulus!